# vb.net HtmlAgilityPack Insert string after div

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to inset some of my own html directly after the end of a div. This div has other div inside of it.

```
    Dim HtmlNode As HtmlNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<span class=""label"">Those were the friends</span>")
    Dim FriendDiv = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='profile_friends']")
    Dim NewHTML As HtmlNode = htmldoc.DocumentNode.InsertAfter(HtmlNode, FriendDiv)
```

Every time I run that code I get an exception `Node "<div class="profile_topfriends"></div>" was not found in the collection`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to [`XmlNode`'s `InsertAfter()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.insertafter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you need to call this method on the common parent of referenced node and to be inserted node. Try something like this :

```
Dim NewHTML As HtmlNode = FriendDiv.ParentNode.InsertAfter(HtmlNode, FriendDiv)
```

Worked fine for me. Here is a simple test I did in C# (translated to VB) :

```
Dim html = "<body><div></div></body>"
Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(html)
Dim div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div")
Dim span = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<span class=""label"">Those were the friends</span>")
Dim newHtml = div.ParentNode.InsertAfter(span, div)
Console.WriteLine(XDocument.Parse(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml).ToString())
```

The `<span>` appears after `<div>` in console.

Comment: FriendDiv was created by HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode. How can I now update the HtmlDocument with the NewHTML?

Comment: What did you mean? `InsertAfter()` should've inserted the `NewHTML` to the `HtmlDocument`

Comment: `<span class=""label"">Those were the friends</span>`is nowhere to be seen in htmldoc.text

Comment: Thanks! I'll just need to assume its all working. Currently I am receiving "The '"' character, hexadecimal value 0x22, cannot be included in a name."