# HtmlAgilityPack The '"' character, hexadecimal value 0x22, cannot be included in a name

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

This line:

```
    Dim NewHTMLString As String = XDocument.Parse(htmldoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml).ToString()
```

Produces this error:

```
    The '"' character, hexadecimal value 0x22, cannot be included in a name.
```

This is the line in the HTML it says is wrong:

```
    if ( typeof JSON != 'object' || !JSON.stringify || !JSON.parse ) { document.write( "<scr" + "ipt type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/blahblah"><\/script>\n" ); };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `XDocument` meant to deal with XML, hence it doesn't support arbitrary Javascript string. `XDocument` thinks this part : `<scr"`, as beginning of an XML node and double-quote (`"`) character in the XML node name is considered invalid.

I was using `XDocument` in the answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334644/vb-net-htmlagilitypack-insert-string-after-div) to get beautifully formatted XML output in console, and I did that because I know exactly that my HTML is XML compliant. In this case, your HTML isn't valid from XML point of view and it isn't clear what you're trying to achieve using `XDocument` here. If you simply need to check result from modification you did to the original HTML, you can either directly print `htmldoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml` to console or save the HTML to a new file like so :

```
htmldoc.Save("path_to_new_file.html")
```